# Does the Hirsch conjecture hold for $n < 2d$?

Tags: linear-programming, co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry

The [Hirsch conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirsch_conjecture) asserts that the graph (i.e. $1$-skeleton) of a $d$-dimensional [convex polytope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytope) with $n$ facets has [diameter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_%28graph_theory%29) at most $n - d$.

After being open for decades, [Francisco Santos has recently proved](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/articles/3941) that this fails in general.

> Is it possible that the conjecture
>   holds for $n < 2d$?  Santos's counterexample had $(n,d) = (86, 43)$.

One observation which may be relevant:  If $n < 2d$, then every pair of vertices has a common facet.  One can use this to show that the general Hirsch conjecture reduces to the $n \ge 2d$ case, (see Ziegler's book *Lectures on Polytopes*, p. 84).  But this doesn't seem to answer the question here.

Comment: A partly-baked idea:  The common facet shared by a pair of vertices is a $(d-1, 2d-2)$ polytope, which might serve as a basis for induction...?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is no, as follows from the following Lemma of Klee and Walkup:

Lemma: If P is a d-polytope with n facets and we perform a "wedge" over any facet F we get a (d+1)-polytope P' with n+1 facets and with diameter(P') $\ge$ diameter(P).

Corollary: since there is a 43-polytope with 86 facets and diameter (at least) 44, for every positive integer k there is a (43+k)-polytope with 86+k facets and diameter at least 44. These polytopes have n<2d.

I take the occasion to announce an update. My recent paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1202.4701 (joint with Matschke and Weibel) contains smaller counter-examples to the Hirsch conjecture. The current record is a polytope with dimension 20, 40 facets, and diameter 21.

Comment: Welcome to Mathoverflow!